# What does this mean in Ace Ventura?

Tags: ace-ventura-pet-detective

There is a line in [*Ace Ventura: Pet Detective* (1994)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109040/) when the police are making fun of him:

> [Uh-oh. I think I heard a toilet flush. Maybe somebody lost a turtle](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109040/characters/nm0135306)

What does that mean? Is that a joke? Why is it funny? Googling it only gives quotes from Ace Ventura as a result. Is it a reference to something else?

Answer (score 5):

The joke is that they're suggesting someone has just flushed a turtle down a toilet, and that Ace should go and look for it (which, given that toilets are involved, would likely be quite messy). So, they're continuing to insult Ace by suggesting a demeaning assignment for him.

Comment: There's an added … ermm… depth to that. Google 'slang turtle's head' & ignore whoever thought it was as late as Austin Powers who thought it up. I's been slang in the UK since at least the 70's.

Comment: Someone already mentioned that but their comment got deleted for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

The old saying, "I've got a turtle looking for water", which means I've got to go poop; the visual of the poop looking like a turtle's head is supposed to elicit laughter.  When you "flush a turtle", it means you've done your business and flushed.  There are lots of off-color references like this, including "Taking the Browns to the Super Bowl".  A few others that may be considered racist so I'll leave them out of here.